# Streaming / saving / serializing internal state of Boost.Numeric.Odeint steppers

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, odeint

I have an application where I need to interrupt ODE evolution after a certain time (or, number of steps), save the state of the system + the ODE engine with binary precision, so that the evolution can be resumed later. It is a requirement that evolution so interrupted cannot differ from uninterrupted evolution.

Saving usually occurs at the end of fairly long trajectories, so it should be assumed that time and disc usage of the serialization stage is not an issue.

So far, I used [GSL odeiv](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/ode-initval.html), wrapped the necessary C objects into a high-level C++ object, and used the [Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library for this latter.

I want to switch to [Boost.Numeric.Odeint](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html), and I hoped that I wouldn’t need to do any wrapping myself. Steppers in this library can have internal state in general (e.g. [multistep methods](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/steppers.html#boost_numeric_odeint.odeint_in_detail.steppers.multistep_methods) store internally part of their history), yet, they do not seem to implement either streaming operators or (de)serialization.

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace O = boost::numeric::odeint;

const bool doContinue = true; // this can be a command-line parameter
const size_t N = 3;
typedef boost::array<double, N> state_type;

static void sys(const state_type& /*x*/, state_type& /*dxdt*/, double /*t*/) {
  // ...
}

int main() {
  // adams_bashforth_moulton stepper example
  double t = 0.0, dt = 0.1;
  state_type inout;
  
  O::adams_bashforth_moulton<5, state_type> abm;
  
  if (!doContinue) {
    abm.initialize(sys, inout, t, dt);
    // integrate for some pretty long time
    for( ; t<10.0 ; t+= dt )
      abm.do_step( sys , inout , t , dt );
    // ...
    // ... save t, inout, and current state of abm to archive ...
    // ...
  }
  else {
    // ...
    // ... retrieve t, inout, and previous state of abm from archive ...
    // ...
    double tEnd=t+10.;
    // continue integration for another pretty long stretch
    for( ; t<tEnd ; t+= dt )
      abm.do_step( sys , inout , t , dt );    
  }
}
```

What is the approved way to save the state of steppers in Boost.Numeric.Odeint with full precision?

I understand that these classes are heavily templated, and the type of the internal state can depend on template parameters, but there might still be some mechanism of retrieving the full internal state. A model might be the pseudo-random-generator engines in STL (e.g. [Mersenne twister](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)): they are also pretty heavily templated, yet they provide streaming operators to save/retrieve their internals.

Comment: Do you have, like, any example of what state you're using? The little experience I have with OdeInt is that everything is a template argument that you can customize

Comment: Not really, my application is also pretty generic, so the requirement has to be fulfilled for any kind of state. (E.g. single complex number, std::valarray, [future std::]mdspan, blitz::array, etc.) But to confirm: the question is specifically for the internal state of the ODE stepper, not the state of the system.

Comment: If it's all those types, what made you expect that the serialisation code is included? That doesn't seem natural since at least a few of them are user-defined/third party. If all that is distracting from "the internal state of the ODE stepper" - what state is that? Can you... perhaps even link to an example?

Comment: Ok, just as an example let’s concentrate on [multistep methods](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/steppers.html#boost_numeric_odeint.odeint_in_detail.steppers.multistep_methods). The linked page emphasizes several times that they store internally some part of their history (as we very well expect they should). This is e.g. what I mean by “state of the ODE stepper”.

Comment: I edited the question to include this example. So I guess my question in this case would be: how do I access and save/load this (partial) history of the multistep methods?

Comment: The example you provide doesn't reflect what you want to do, including strange thing defined elsewhere. Also, you have access to the "state of the system" before and after any number of steps. Why don't you serialize that? A secondary note is that any complicated stepper might have more state that the "system state", including copies of the system, you don't want that. My recommendation is 1) use a method that gives the same result when steps are composed in sequence 2) serialize the state of the system in between steps. ODEint doesn't really have much to do with this.

Comment: Agree with @alfc. Also serializing can be time consuming. Maybe you should work with a [memory mapped file](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files), ensuring that the file is written at some "critical" step in the calculation. That way you should be able to recover from a crash. Serializing is dedicated to save data in a file that you could open on another OS.

Comment: @sehe sorry, I don’t get the example you added. Why is there a new initialization after `do_step`? How does this snippet reflect retrieving (saving) and resetting (loading) the internal state of `abm`?

Comment: @alfC saving the full state of even a complicated stepper is exactly what I want, I think. The point is that when I resume the saved evolution from disc, it should continue as if an interruption has not occured. I specifically want to use multistep methods in this application.

Comment: @JeanDavy I added “Saving usually occurs at the end of fairly long trajectories, so it should be assumed that time and disc usage of the serialization stage is not an issue.” to the original question. It’s not like I want to be prepared against a crash at any time.

Comment: @HyperBoar I was saving other people the 25 minutes I spent tracking down **any** example with that stepper. Why didn't you add it? You wouldn't have a strange conversation with about stranger adding "the wrong thing"....

Comment: On topic: it doesn't look like ODEINT affords this (although you can copy states, and the concepts are generically tractable to an extent, so you **might** write an extension. Point is: not without using undocumented library details). Have you considered freezing an entire process space (either with signals or using something ? This would have the benefit of working regardless of the implementation. "Process Migration" is a topic that has had some research, including checkpoint/resume

Comment: @sehe I haven’t yet considered process migration, but it sounds like a very powerful idea, thanks for the suggestion! Indeed, from what I understand of it, it seems conceptually much more robust than saving object states.